# How does a bottle spin?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am preparing for my exam next monday and I decided to try and make some old exams. This is one exercise that i was not sure of.

Assume a bottle is laying on an assembly line? (apologies for bad english), with the length axis perpendicular on the moving direction of the bottle, so that the bottle will be able to spin. The assembly line is moving at a speed $V(t)$, assume rolling without slipping and find the equation of motion for the center of mass.

The bottle can be simplified as a non-uniform cylinder with a moment of inertia of $Mk^2$, with k a constant, and has a radius of $a$.

I thought that the acceleration of the center of mass, $$M\cdot dv/dt=F=M\cdot dV(t)/dt$$, and the equation for rotation, $$dL/dt=\sum \text{torque}=a \times  F=a\cdot M\cdot dV(t)/dt\cdot\sin(\theta),$$ thus $$L(t)=I\cdot\omega=\int a\cdot M\cdot dV(t)/dt\cdot\sin(\theta) dt,$$ with the start condition, that $V(t)=v(t)=0$. So $$I\cdot\omega=a\cdot M\cdot\sin(\theta)\cdot V(t),$$ and $$\omega=v(t)/a$$ thus $$v(t)=a^2\cdot M\cdot\sin(\theta)\cdot V(t)/I$$.

Comment: What is your specific conceptual question? We don't do "check my work."

Comment: The question is, how you would solve such a question.